The [..collection] operator mean in C#
when I was checking the official Microsoft C# documentation recently, I saw an operator [..collections] that uses very little to encapsulate collections, as shown in the figure below: Does anyone know how to use this operator? Or There is an explanation about this operator, thank you!

This problem has troubled me for many days

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. and you can read this: Collection expressions

Thanks @Johnathan, I just realised my error and was going to edit in that one :)
